# Conditional column calculation with different value for every second rows in r

Tags: r

Given column 1 that has A,B, and C values, how to create column 2 under this condition:
- If column 1 is either A or B, column 2 would be F,F1,F,F1 (every second cell be F1), otherwise, same C.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `transform` with `ifelse`

```
transform(df, Col2 = ifelse(Col1 %in% c("A", "B"), c("F", "F1"), Col1))

#   Col1 Col2
#1     A    F
#2     A   F1
#3     A    F
#4     A   F1
#5     A    F
#6     A   F1
#7     B    F
#8     B   F1
#9     B    F
#10    B   F1
#11    B    F
#12    C    C
#13    C    C
#14    C    C
#15    C    C
```

Probably, using it by group is more appropriate.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Col1) %>% 
  mutate(Col2 = ifelse(Col1 %in% c("A", "B"), c("F", "F1"), Col1))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 6:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```